# Symfony Serializer Component AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS denormalize

Tags: symfony, callback, symfony4, normalization, serialization

I am trying to use Serialize with callbacks like in https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances . But it doesn't seem to go into the callback. I can ignore attributes with 'IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES' just fine, just CALLBACKS not working. What could I be doing wrong?

```
$dateCallback = function ($innerObject, $outerObject, string $attributeName, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
            dump('foo');
            return 'faa';
        };        
$defaultContext = [
            AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
                'order_date' => $dateCallback,
            ]
        ];        
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, null, null, null,  $defaultContext);
$serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], []);
$order = $serializer->denormalize($data, Orderform::class, 'array');
```

The data is a simple array.

```
$data = ['order_date' => '2020-07-07',
'order_number' => '123'];
```

I would expect the $dateCallback to be called. But it doesn't seem to do that. The Orderform entity is getting populated but not with the value I would expect from the callback.
I tried making all this with json and xml too, since array doesn't show up in the documentation (but it works except for the callback)

Symfony 4.4

Comment: What are you trying to archive with callback while denormalizing? Maybe what you want is deserialize.

Comment: @FelipeChagas I changed it to deserialize. But still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't debug your code, instead I made a working version of the deserialization example based on the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object), hope it's serve as guide:

```
<?php 

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

//
//Inializing the Serializer, enconders and callbacks
//
$encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
$dateCallback = function ($innerObject, $outerObject, string $attributeName, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
    return $innerObject instanceof \DateTime ? $innerObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') : '';
};

$defaultContext = [
    AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
        'createdAt' => $dateCallback,
    ]
];

$normalizer = [new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, null, null, null,  $defaultContext)];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizer, $encoders);

//
//Creating Object Person that will be serialized
//
$person = new Person();
$person->setName('foo');
$person->setAge(99);
$person->setSportsperson(false);
$person->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

$arrayContent = $serializer->serialize($person, 'json');

// $arrayContent contains ["name" => "foo","age" => 99,"sportsperson" => false,"createdAt" => null]
//print_r($arrayContent); // or return it in a Response

// Lets deserialize it
$desrializedPerson = $serializer->deserialize($arrayContent, Person::class, 'json');

var_dump($desrializedPerson);

//
// Foo Bar stuff
//

// Entity Person declaration 
class Person
{
    private $age;
    private $name;
    private $sportsperson;
    private $createdAt;

    // Getters
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    // Issers
    public function isSportsperson()
    {
        return $this->sportsperson;
    }

    // Setters
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function setSportsperson($sportsperson)
    {
        $this->sportsperson = $sportsperson;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }
}
```